# Error with arabtex

Tags: errors, compiling, arabtex

I'm already write a text with ArabTex but I have an error with compilation such that I read the arabtexdoc but I don't find the solution

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{mathbbol}
\begin{document}
\novocalize
\begin{arabtex}
\begin{itemize}
\item[$I)$] ltkn $g$ AldAlT Al`dadyT Alm`rfT `lY $]0,+\infty[$ bmAyly $:$ 
\begin{equation}
g(x)=x^2-1+2x^2ln(x)
\end{equation}
\end{itemize}
\end{arabtex}
\end{document}
```

I got this error
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.